Removing DC offset from AD8220 output (Instrumentation Amplifier) in electromagnetic application
I'm using AD8220 to amplifying a very tiny signal, which is made by a electrode in a electromagnetic flow meter. In the voltage that is made by the electrode there is an DC offset, then this DC offset is being feed to AD8220. The range of the DC offset voltage is 10-300 mV depending of the water characteristic, which is passing through the meter. In the flowing drawing we can see the circuit:

I need to remove this DC offset form the output of the AD8220, the approach should be fast enough for my measurement step, not having a big delay (the signal will be sampled by an ADC) and this process should be in real-time, would you please let me know your ideas about this?

Regards
Reference: https://www.mecon.de/en/magnetic-inductive-flow-meters/

This is almost a good question. Not quite. Talk about the sample rate, please. Talk about the delay, too. And any allowable errors.

Your circuit won't work properly. Have you considered that your design might be the problem? Please also link to a document that explains the working principle of the flowmeter.

You don't have inputs "return" path ... Add 2 identical resistors (something like 1 Meg Ohm) to the ground at inputs.

<<< When an electrically conductive fluide flows in the pipe, an electrode voltage E is induced between a pair of electrodes placed at right angles to the direction of magnetic field. >>> https://www.global.toshiba/ww/products-solutions/smart-manufacturing/field-intelligent-device/product/magmeter/principle-and-feature.html#:~:text=The%20electromagnetic%20flowmeter%20uses%20Faraday's,the%20direction%20of%20magnetic%20field.

How does your approach discriminate signal from offset? The ADC only sees "some voltage"

The offset would cancel out if you use AC to feed the coil.

The simplest thing to do with out doing anything is subtracting the offset at system start up in firmware.

@Jens we are using AC signal (30-40 Hz) to feed the coils and we still have the offset.

I assume the electrodes have direct contact to the fluid, which has a DC potential different from your amplifier. This maybe some mV or V caused by galvanic effects. Did you try using input capacitors?

@Jens would you please elaborate more how I can use input capacitor? where should I put them?

For a helpful answer I would like to see a schematic of the actual AD8220 circuit. Split or single supply? Isolated or with connection to PE? Input resistors to GND? Any RF filters? What is the gain?

@Jens I added a schematic in the post

@periblepsis regarding the sample rate 2400 sample/second, the delay should be as small as possible, considering it tis an ultra-low power application (battery based), so delay really maters in the consumption. For being more accurate I added also an full schematic of  my design in this post , I would appreciate if you can give me your feedback base on this data, thanks in advance.

Simulated with microcap v12.
Made with AD8221 (quasi-same amplifier ...)
Complete circuit with resistors bias and Vref polarization of 2.5 V (mid-supply voltage).
Better is a double symmetric power supply +/- 2.5 V or +/- 5 V (Vref = 0 V).
One can note that there is a DC offset depending on the value of the bias resistors
(1 Meg -> 3.30 mV, 10 Meg -> ~35 mV, ...).
See use of figure 67 of AD8220 datasheet


would you please let me know which software have you used for simulation?

Made with microcap v12 https://gotroot.ca/spectrum/www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.html

The signals are AC and fixed frequency so the DC offset can be removed with capacitive coupling very well.
The offset can be removed before or after the amplifier depending on the available input and output range of the in-amp. The various instrumentation amp app-notes cover AC-coupling the input - there must always be a DC path to ground.

Thank you for the answer, when using capacitive coupling it is recommended to use a 1M Ohm resistor as well, which can make high frequency filter, but the issue here is that there will be a lot of delay in the system around 10-20 seconds, which is not acceptable for low power application. Is there any other solution that is fast?

Don’t use an in-amp. They are often redundant today. Connect the inputs directly to a 24-bit ADC. The modern ones will have enough resolution and input range for your need. You will digitally demodulate the carrier in a narrow-band, vastly improving the S/N ratio. Sigma delta ADCs have outputs that are very amenable to such filtering.
